# $\mathtt{PSP}$ holding only for sets of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

Consider the sentence $\mathtt{PSP}_\mathfrak{c}$: "Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ having the cardinality of the continuum contains a Cantor set".
A priori this sentence is weaker than the usual $\mathtt{PSP}$, since $\mathtt{PSP}_\mathfrak{c}$ requires the set not only to be uncountable, but to be of the size of the continuum.

My questions are:

- Given a model $M$ of $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+\mathtt{PSP}_\mathfrak{c}$, can we find a forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ in $M$ such that for any $G$ $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$, the extension $M[G]$ satisfies $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+\mathtt{PSP}$?
- More in general, can we prove that $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+\mathtt{PSP}_\mathfrak{c}$ is equiconsistent with $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+\mathtt{PSP}$?
- Is it consistent $\mathtt{ZF}+\mathtt{DC}+\mathtt{PSP}_\mathfrak{c}+\neg\mathtt{PSP}$, modulo the consistency of some large cardinal?

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the answers you're looking for:

1. No.
2. No.
3. Yes, no large cardinals needed! (Which explains the previous two answers.)

Look no further than John Truss' paper:

> *Truss, John*, [**Models of set theory containing many perfect sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4843(74)90015-1), Ann. Math. Logic 7, 197-219 (1974). [ZBL0302.02024](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0302.02024).

There he shows that by just adding many Cohen reals to $L$ we can have a model of $\sf ZF+DC$ in which every set of reals is well-orderable or contains a perfect set. Moreover, we can choose an arbitrarily high Hartogs numbers for the reals, so there can be many well-orderable cardinals intermediate to the continuum.

This provides us with a model of $\sf PSP_{\frak c}$ that requires no large cardinals. However, since $\sf PSP$ implies that $\omega_1$ is inaccessible to reals, that means we cannot extend further to a model of full $\sf DC+PSP$ without an inaccessible cardinal present.